# Automatic white balance in iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, gpuimage

I'm trying to fix the white balance of a picture on iOS.
In my app, people can take a picture and get 2 things : an OCR and an "improved" version of the image.

To do the OCR, I improve the image with GPUImage (using `GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter`). But that image is made only of black and white pixels. For my "improved" version, I want to have :
- the right color balance (meaning my white is really white and not yellow when I take the picture inside)
- good contrast.

I tried with `GPUImageContrastFilter` and `GPUImageWhiteBalanceFilter`. `GPUImageWhiteBalanceFilter` works well but `GPUImageWhiteBalanceFilter` takes parameters (like `temperature`) and that really depends on the image input.

So is there a way to "calculate" these parameters or are there objective c algorithms to fix white balance ? Either ready to use, or simple using GPUImage ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CoreImage` to auto enhance images. It will do the analysis for you.

This is done by acquiring a set of `CIFilter` with the necessary modifications that you can just apply to your image.

See more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_autoadjustment/ci_autoadjustmentSAVE.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH11-SW1).

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

It may take time, but you can use your OCR function as a kind of scoring algorithm for a hill-climbing (or other) optimization algorithm.

1. Take a portion of the image (to speed it up)
2. Pick some parameters and improve the image
3. Run it through OCR -- hopefully your OCR can give some confidence or you have some way of scoring the output (number of words?)
4. Change the parameters -- use an optimization algorithm to decide how to do this.
5. Go to 3 -- stop when you run out of time or it's good enough

If OCR is too slow -- you may have to pick something else to score with.  Perhaps there's a way to compare your output images with known good ones and get a diff.

Comment: I actually have no problem with the OCR. The "OCR version" is OK and my OCR works well; I'm looking to have an automatically enhanced picture (especially with better white balance). I'm going to have a look at @Artal solution